# i want to show my recyclerview latest added item in top of the recyclerview not end

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, reverse

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.studentregister.db.Student

class StudentRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val clickListener:(Student)->Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentViewHolder>(){
    private val studentList=ArrayList<Student>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StudentViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val listItem=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
        return StudentViewHolder(listItem)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StudentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(studentList[position],clickListener)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return studentList.size
    }

    fun setList(students:List<Student>){
        studentList.clear()
        studentList.addAll(students)
    }

}
class StudentViewHolder(private val view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    fun bind(student: Student,clickListener:(Student)->Unit){
        val nametextview=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvname)
        val emailtextview=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvemail)
        nametextview.text = student.name
        emailtextview.text = student.email
        view.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(student)
        }
    }
}
```

i am building a student name email register app in kotlin and that info saved in database and showed in recycler view i want to show the latest added information on top of the recyclerview and all the latest added record will show on the top not on the end of recycler view i want to reverse recycler view
this is my main activity code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.studentregister.db.Student
import com.example.studentregister.db.StudentDatabase

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var nameedittext:EditText
    private lateinit var emailedittext:EditText
    private lateinit var savebutton:Button
    private lateinit var clearbutton:Button
    private lateinit var viewModel: StudentViewModel
    private lateinit var studentRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: StudentRecyclerViewAdapter
    private var islistitemClicked=false
    private lateinit var selectedStudent: Student
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        nameedittext=findViewById(R.id.etname)
        emailedittext=findViewById(R.id.etemail)
        savebutton=findViewById(R.id.btnsave)
        clearbutton=findViewById(R.id.btnclear)
        studentRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rvstudent)
        val dao=StudentDatabase.getInstance(application).studentDao()
        val factory=StudentViewModelFactory(dao)
        viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(StudentViewModel::class.java)
        savebutton.setOnClickListener {
            if (islistitemClicked) {
                updatestudentdata()
                clearInput()
            } else {
                saveStudentData()
                clearInput()
            }
        }
        clearbutton.setOnClickListener {
            if(islistitemClicked){
                deletestudentdata()
                clearInput()
            }else{
                clearInput()
            }
        }
        initRecyclerView()
    }
    private fun saveStudentData(){
        viewModel.insertStudent(
            Student(
                0,
                nameedittext.text.toString(),
                emailedittext.text.toString()
            )
        )
    }
    private fun updatestudentdata(){
        viewModel.updateStudent(
            Student(
                selectedStudent.id,
                nameedittext.text.toString(),
                emailedittext.text.toString()
            )
        )
        savebutton.text="Save"
        clearbutton.text="Clear"
        islistitemClicked = false
    }
    private fun deletestudentdata(){
        viewModel.deleteStudent(
            Student(
                selectedStudent.id,
                nameedittext.text.toString(),
                emailedittext.text.toString()
            )
        )
        savebutton.text="Save"
        clearbutton.text="Clear"
        islistitemClicked = false
    }
    private fun clearInput(){
        nameedittext.setText("")
        emailedittext.setText("")
    }
    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        studentRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = StudentRecyclerViewAdapter{
            selectedItem:Student -> listitemclicked(selectedItem)
        }
        studentRecyclerView.adapter=adapter
        displayStudentList()
    }
    private fun displayStudentList(){
        viewModel.Students.observe(this,{
            adapter.setList(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
    private fun listitemclicked(student: Student){
        //Toast.makeText(this,"student name is ${student.name}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        selectedStudent = student
        savebutton.text="Update"
        clearbutton.text="Delete"
        islistitemClicked = true
        nameedittext.setText(selectedStudent.name)
        emailedittext.setText(selectedStudent.email)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Kotlin** :

```
   val itemList = (0..10).toMutableList()
```

> Result : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Append

```
itemList.add(index = 0, 100)
```

> Result : [100, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

You have to use mutablelist / arrayList for operation **.add(index, data)** .
As **List** it cant be add.